# Replace blank in single csv column throughout multiple files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to sift through a batch of CSV files (using | as delimiter but prepared to replace pipes with commas if needed) replacing any blank field with another value using PowerShell.
The CSVs don't have headers, so I need to add headers to focus on column 3, but the file written back to disk needs to not have these headers.

I've tried the following with no luck. It seems to do nothing:

```
  $files = Get-ChildItem "~\Desktop\Test\*.csv"
foreach ($f in $files)
{
    $outfile = $f.FullName + "mod"
    $data = Import-csv $f -Header A , B , C , D , E , F , G
$data |
   ForEach-Object {
$_.C = $_.C -replace "" , "BLANK"}
}
```

Comment: use the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet to get the data in csv format,  strip out the 1st line, and then save that as a csv file with `Set-Content`.

Comment: Why set `$outfile` if you never use it? You're not exporting anything.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - the files are CSVs but just pipe delimited rather than comma. Changing to comma isn't an issue for me

Comment: @Abraham Zinala - I want to write the modified file back to the folder

Comment: @KevW - if you use the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet, it can make a csv formatted array of strings. then you can remove the 1st line - the unwanted header line. finally, you can write that array of strings to a file with `Set-Content`. **_that is what you said you wanted ... a CSV file with the header line removed._**

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hi Lee, sorry I may not have explained properly. I'm fairly clueless. My CSVs don't have headers so I need to create them in order to deal with the 3rd column data. Then I want to replace all blanks ("") in the 3rd column with the work BLANK. Then remove the headers and write the file back to the folder under a different name - ie keep the original intact. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I should probably add that I can't do this in Excel as there are up to 8 million rows in each csv

Comment: @KevW - from what i understand [perhaps wrong], this otta do what you describe --- [1] import the file with `Import-CSV`. this may not work if the file is too large. ///// [2] find & fill  in the empty properties. ///// [3] use `ConvertTo-Csv` to convert your modified collection to an array of CSV lines. ///// [4] remove the 1st line of the resulting array of lines. ///// [5] write the new "csv" to a file with `Set-Content`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - that's great thanks. But sadly I haven't the faintest idea how to modify my script above to do what you suggest.

Comment: @KevW - use the code you have and assign the output of the `foreach` loop to a $Var. then feed that to `ConvertTo-Csv` & assign that to another $Var. strip out the 1st line of that 2nd $Var with `$var[1..-1]` and assign that to a 3rd $Var. finally ... feed the 3rd $Var to `Set-Content`. ///// i would post a demo, but i am to lazy to make the test files to test my code on. [*blush*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Thanks though I'm non the wiser.

Comment: if you don't understand that ... then you likely otta NOT be doing any coding. [*grin*] if you want me to do the demo code for you, then you need to add 2 or 3 sample CSV files [just the 1st 3 lines or so] to your Question so that i can work on a concrete "thing". i am pretty lousy at abstract stuff ... [*grin*]